# How to Update a Microsoft Project Sub-Project Using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-project

We are attempting to update the status date in the sub-projects of a Schedule using VBA following the suggestions [here](https://azlav.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/setting-subproject-status-date-with-vba/) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d7fb11fb-93d4-4897-946b-4a22d77a0f8c/status-date-in-master-projects?forum=projectserver2010general). Ideally we'd like to keep the files closed while doing so, but are open to suggestions if that isn't strictly possible.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
If ActiveProject.Subprojects.count > 0 Then
    Dim msg: msg = MsgBox("Change Status Date for unopened Subprojects?", vbYesNo, "Change Status Dates for Unopened Subprojects?")
    Dim subp As SubProject
    If msg = vbYes Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Updating Sub-Projects..."
        For Each subp In ActiveProject.Subprojects
            subp.SourceProject.StatusDate = newDate
            subp.SourceProject.SaveAs subp.SourceProject.Name
        Next
    End If
End If
```

This **appears** to work, however when we open the sub-project files the Status Date hasn't changed (as seen on Project > Status > Status Date). The date below is the same before and after:

[image]

Alternatives that also have not worked.

1. We've tried setting `Projects(subp.SourceProject.Name).StatusDate`:

```
If ActiveProject.Subprojects.count > 0 Then
    Dim msg: msg = MsgBox("Change Status Date for unopened Subprojects?", vbYesNo, "Change Status Dates for Unopened Subprojects?")
    Dim subp As SubProject
    If msg = vbYes Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Updating Sub-Projects..."
        For Each subp In ActiveProject.Subprojects
            Projects(subp.SourceProject.Name).StatusDate = newDate
            subp.SourceProject.SaveAs subp.SourceProject.Name
        Next
    End If
End If
```

2. We've tried to open the sub-projects first and then to change the value (we've tried both FileOpen & FileOpenEx):

```
If ActiveProject.Subprojects.count > 0 Then
    Dim msg: msg = MsgBox("Change Status Date for unopened Subprojects?", vbYesNo, "Change Status Dates for Unopened Subprojects?")
    Dim subp As SubProject
    If msg = vbYes Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Updating Sub-Projects..."
        For Each subp In ActiveProject.Subprojects
            FileOpen subp.SourceProject.Path
            subp.SourceProject.StatusDate = newDate
            FileClose pjSave
        Next
    End If
End If
```

3. And then we've tried saving the sub-projects in various ways using:

- `subp.SourceProject.SaveAs subp.SourceProject.Name`
- `Projects(subp.SourceProject.path).SaveAs subp.SourceProject.Name`

As an interesting data point, we do notice that both the `SourceProject.StatusDate` and `Projects(subp.SourceProject.Name).StatusDate` for a given sub-project are what we set them to, even if the sub-project, once opened in MSP, does not reflect the value in the interface.

Note: we have tried closing/re-opening and manual save all (user input). No go.

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

**EDIT #1**

Note that we have also attempted saving the master schedule following the loop using two methods.

First, code leading up to the save:

```
    'save name of Master Schedule to imsProj
    dim imsProj as string: imsProj = ActiveProj.Name 
    If ActiveProject.Subprojects.count > 0 Then
         'Here is where we run the above loop
    End If
    
    'Ensure the Master Schedule is the active project
    Projects(imsProj).Activate

    'Master Schedule save goes here. See below.
```

Then:

Save Method 1

```
    'Save all open Projects, including master
    For i = 1 To Projects.count
        Projects(i).SaveAs Projects(i).Name
    Next i
```

Save Method 2:

```
FileSave
```

Neither works.

Is there a setting in MSP that we are not considering?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to save each subproject individually, save the entire master at the end. Turning of alerts prevents a pop-up confirmation box for each subproject.

```
Sub SetSubProjectStatusDate()

Dim newDate As Date
newDate = #1/11/2022#

If ActiveProject.Subprojects.Count > 0 Then
    Dim msg As VbMsgBoxResult
    msg = MsgBox("Change Status Date for unopened Subprojects?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion _
        , "Change Status Dates?")
    If msg = vbYes Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Updating Sub-Projects..."
        Dim subp As Subproject
        For Each subp In ActiveProject.Subprojects
            subp.SourceProject.StatusDate = newDate
        Next
        DisplayAlerts = False
        FileSave
        DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should've noted that we are saving following the loop as well. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is incredibly frustrating, but it appears the IMS and its subprojects were somehow corrupted. No evident cause, no evident effect other than with how the status dates appear. Using a fresh set of MPPs resolved the matter.

Here is the final working code:

```
If ActiveProject.Subprojects.count > 0 Then
    Dim msg: msg = MsgBox("Change Status Date for unopened Subprojects?", vbYesNo, "Change Status Dates for Unopened Subprojects?")
    Dim subp As SubProject
    If msg = vbYes Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Updating Sub-Projects..."
        For Each subp In ActiveProject.Subprojects
            subp.SourceProject.StatusDate = temp
        Next
    End If
End If

Projects(imsProj).Activate

FileSave
```